# Is my xcode project duplicating itself?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an **`Xcode`** project. I see that there is a folder within the project folder in my `Finder` with exactly the same name as the project folder and this folder contains a copy of the project and includes, you guessed it, a copy of the project within again and again. The project folder is now 5Gb while the app itself is no more than 25Mb. So I think that the project somehow is making copies of itself. I see that in my Project I have two targets, one of the project name and one with the project name + "- copy" at the end of the target name.
I wonder what I should do to stop my project increasing in size and how to safely remove the copied project folder within.

Comment: Do you have any idea as to what is causing the duplication? Obviously, you don't have the answer otherwise you wouldn't post this. But do you have any clue as to *when* the project is duplicated? Does your intuition say it's Xcode messing op, or is some other process on your computer possibly duplicating files? Are any other files or folders being inadvertently duplicated? Perhaps you are accidentally mis-using the Command-D shortcut key to do something (which duplicates items in the Finder). Do you have any idea what is causing this, at all? Any hunch could help.

Comment: You could also check the resources included in your Xcode project (more specifically the 'Copy Bundle Resources' build phase) to see if the project contains a non-wanted recursive reference to itself somewhere.

Comment: At the beginning of the project a few weeks back I think I set up the target so that I would have a copy to go back to if I screwed things up along the way, is it possible I have pointed the project target at itself? Does the target make a copy of the project? will it be safe to just MOVE the mirror folder out from under the project folder in Finder and also remove the copy Target?

Comment: Unless you're actually building the copied target, I don't think that plays a role. (And I'm guessing you're building the original, modified target, is that right?). I think you can safely move the mirror folder and remove the copy Target, but keep a copy around somewhere else just to be sure; I don't want to recommend you throw it away directly because you might lose something.

Comment: I followed those steps and the issue has become redundant. Thanks for your thoughts Wilbo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was a copy of the project in the target, the solution is to remove the offending folder form within the project in finder and then to remove the copied project in the target.